# Using Collect Values in ArcGIS ModelBuilder with submodel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, iterator

I have a large model with submodels.

Basically the Model iterates through all Districts, selects in each district an attribute above a certain threshold, creates a layerfile of it. The submodel iterates through all the Attributes of the created layerfile and then selects the neighbor of this attribute below a certain threshold and creates another layerfile of it.

In the end I want to merge the layerfiles. I though of using a collect value tool to collect all the layerfiles (red circle) which got created in the iterations in the submodel and then add a Merge tool to it in the main model ( or should it be in the submodel)? However, I get no result if I add it to display.

The whole Model works if I just run it and see the result for the last run in the iterator.

Can anyone help me with this? I attached the model but the jpeg probably doesn't make any sense as the text is too small.

I also asked the question on Geonet: https://geonet.esri.com/message/609161

[image: Mainmodel:]

[image: Submodel:]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is being answered on another forum (https://geonet.esri.com/message/609161).